# Passing Class objects in java

Tags: java, class

I have an Interface and 2 concrete class that implement that interface,

```
public interface ITemplate{}

public Template implements ITemoplate {}
public Template2 implements ITemplate {}
```

I have a method that takes in the Class object and instantiates it.

```
public addTemplate(Class<ITemplate> template){
    pipe.add(template.newInstance())
}
```

The problem is that when I call that method, it throws a compile time error:

```
instance.addTemplate(Template.class)
```

> Compile Time Error :

```
addTemplate(java.package.ITemplate.class) cannot be applied to addTemplate(java.package.Template.class)
```

Am I missing something, or is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Class<ITemplate>` will strictly accept the `ITemplate.class`

`Class<? extends ITemplate>` will accept any of the classes implementing `ITemplate.class`

Answer (score 1):

try this method:

```
// works for all classes that inherit from ITemplate.
public addTemplate(Class< ? extends ITemplate> template){ 
    pipe.add(template.newInstance())
}
```

instead of

```
// only accepts ITemplate Type Class (Strict Type).
public addTemplate(Class<ITemplate> template){ 
    pipe.add(template.newInstance())
}
```

Here is an explanation: when you use `Class<ITemplate>` it is a strict type of class `Itemplate`. It will never take any other type argument other than `ITemplate`, because it is resolved at compile time only.
However `Class <? extends ITemplate>` can accept all objects that are either `ITemplate` or have `ITemplate` as a superclass.